# Short-Circuit Protection for 3-6 Volts AA batteries

Tags: batteries, mosfet, short-circuit, p-channel

I’m looking for a circuit that can protect 3-6 Volts AA Batteries when a short-circuit happens. When the short-circuit happens, a second circuit (LED blinking) must be triggered and the batteries must be protected. The goal is that the LED won’t stop blinking until the short-circuit is undone. What are cheap suitable options for this application? Efuse, p-channel mosfet, x2 transistor arrange, Ideal diodes, a Battery protection CI? Could someone give me hand?

Comment: What exactly is '3-6 Volts AA Batteries'?

Comment: You need a current sensing resistor and a bjt to set a latch which will turn off a mosfet/bjt. The latch needs to have power even when rest of circuit is off.

Answer (score 1):

A very popular solution to protecting batteries is the DW01A ic. Super common from chinese protection boards. You need just a few basic components with it I believe, like a current sense resistor and a P channel mosfet